# VirtuaNes on pc has some problems

Tags: nes, mighty-final-fight

I love the NES game "Mighty Final Fight". I want to use cheats to make the game even more fun to play but whenever I type cheat code (most of them are not considered as cheat codes by virtual NES) which are recognized by Virtual NES and I even enable them 'always' but I did not see any effect of the code. What could be the problem?

Also, in my game there is a fire kick move (possessed by guy) which does not work.
To do it: A, backward, forward + B
But he does not do the move at all. Is this a problem in the Emulator or my PC or emulators don't support that move?
But this is my second problem, I have no problem if it is left unanswered but my main problem is cheats.

Comment: Someone delete this question it has been solved

Comment: If you have solved this, you can self-answer. If you want it deleted, you can delete your own questions, as long as there's no upvoted answer.

Comment: @Frank I don't have reputation on this site so I can't delete it.

Comment: You don't have rep, but you don't need it to delete your own questions.

Comment: @Frank how do I delete it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VirtuaNES might not read some codes. Just find the code's binary address and locate it in cheat support. Then click on **code append **and enter binary address then save it.